# Составление схемы предложения

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

> Мы полагаем, что во всякой истине всегда есть нечто ложное и что сходство между истиной и ложью так велико, что нет такого отличительного признака, на основании которого можно было бы судить наверняка.

Схема: `[...], (...) и (...), (...), (...)`

Правильна ли схема предложения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[...полагаем],  (что...) и (что...так велико), (что...), (которого...).

Однородные изъяснительные придаточные связаны союзом И, последовательное подчинение трех придаточных: изъяснительного, степени/следствия и определительного.

Answer (score 0):

Составленная Вами схема  правильная.